# Linear Combination of Monotonic increasing Function is Monotonic increasing.

Tags: real-analysis

As i know that linear combination of monotonic increasing is monotonic increasing.Since y=x is monotonic increasing and another function y=[x](integral part of x) is also monotonic increasing 
  Now 
       x-[x]={x} .{x} is fractional part of x which is not monotonic.please help me .IF i am incorrect please tell breifly .I m very confused.  THANK YOU

Comment: Many people regard the use of all capitals as shouting, and therefore find it rude.

Comment: Anyway, it clearly isn't true that $\textit {any}$ linear combination of such functions is another such.  $x$ and $2x$ are both montonically increasing but $x-2x=-x$ is not.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1501551/775831

Comment: You are misreading that question.  Saying that a sum of good terms is good is not the same as saying that an arbitrary linear combination of good terms is good.  Please check my example (or yours, for that matter).

Comment: I m really confused sir .

Comment: They form a convex cone, but not a subspace.

Comment: @lulu From the link which i have given in comment box..it is clear that sum of two monotonic increasing function is monotonic increasing ...and you are doing same x-2x ..but where is difference..please explain

Answer (score 1):

$-f(x)$ is a linear combination of $f(x)$, but does not share its "increasingness".

---

Anyway, if

$$u<v\implies f(u)\le f(v)\land g(u)\le g(v)$$

we do have
$$u<v\implies af(u)\le af(v)\land bg(u)\le bg(v)$$

and

$$u<v\implies af(u)+bg(u)\le af(v)+bg(v)$$

provided $a,b\ge 0$ !

Comment: Why do you restrict $a, b$ to be greater than $1$?

Comment: Yes, obviously, I was attempting to joke! :)

Comment: @Allawonder: sorry, I didn't get it because of different factors...

Comment: No worries. I'm sometimes not a very good joker...

Comment: @Allawonder: different factors...