# Can any real function be expressed as sum of increasing and decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

I want to know if any real function can be expressed as:
$f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ such as $g(x)$ is an increasing function and $h(x)$ is a decreasing function?
thanks

Comment: Could you share your thoughts? For example, How would you represent $f(x)=x^2$ like this?

Comment: I don't understand could you please explain !?

Comment: What did you attempt to do to solve this problem?

Comment: to be honest, i think we can't express a function like so, so i went to "argument to absurdity" 
i said let's supose f(x)=g(x)+h(x)---
g is increasing so if x1<x2 then g(x1)<g(x2) so g(x1)-g(x2)<0---
h is decreasing so if x1<x2 then h(x1)>h(x2) so h(x1)-h(x2)>0---
then i suposed f increasing, in order to end up with something wrong 
so if  x1<x2 then f(x1)<(x2) ---
g(x1)+h(x1)<g(x2)+h(x2)---
g(x1)-g(x2)<h(x2)-h(x1)---
... that's what i tried to do :/

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141338/bounded-variation-difference-of-two-increasing-functions

Comment: To start with, in order to have a precise question, you should define what you mean by "increasing" and "decreasing". Do you mean that $x\lt y\implies g(x)\lt g(y),$ or do you mean $x\lt y\implies g(x)\le g(y)$? Anyway the answer is no. For one thing, $g(x)+h(x)$ can have at most countably many discontinuities.

Comment: On the other hand, it's true for functions of [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation).

Comment: @S.C.B. If $f(x)=x^2$ you can take, for example, $g(x)=x+x^2H(x)$ (where $H(x)$ is the [Heaviside unit step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function); then $g(x)$ is strictly increasing and $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Nice comments though,any example of a function which cannot be written as the sum of an increasing function and an decreasing function ?especially by @bof relating to countable discontinuity ?

Comment: @BAYMAX The [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function), being discontinuous everywhere, cannot be written as the sum of two monotone functions.

Comment: @bof ok as in the dirichlet function there are uncountable no. of discontinuities but in the sum of continuous functions being continuous has only countable number of discontinuities and hence giving contradiction..ok can we give an example of continuous function ?

Comment: $f(x)=x\sin\frac1x$ with $f(0)=0.$

Answer (score 3):

The difference of two increasing functions is a function of [Bounded Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation). Note that this answers your question.