# A function of bounded variation on an interval is differentiable a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering is a function of bounded variation on an interval is differentiable a.e? If it is true, how to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Bounded variation, difference of two increasing functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141338/bounded-variation-difference-of-two-increasing-functions)

Answer (score 3):

A function of bounded variation can be written as the difference of two increasing functions. Increasing functions are differentiable a.e. QED