# Axiomatizing convergent sequences and limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The usual exposition of limits of sequences starts with a definition and then derives properties like linearity. I'm curious if, conversely, a reasonable set of these properties characterize the subspace $C_{\text{std}} \subset \mathbf{R}^\mathbf{N}$ of convergent sequences and the map $L_{\text{std}}: C_{\text{std}} \to \mathbf{R}, (a_n) \mapsto \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$. Here is an example list of properties (when I say equivalently, I mean equivalent assuming the previous conditions):

1. $C$ is a vector subspace and $L: C \to \mathbf{R}$ is $\mathbf{R}$-linear.
2. $C$ contains all monotone bounded sequences.
3. If $a$ is eventually the constant $a_\infty$, ie $a_n = a_\infty$ for large $n$, then $La = a_\infty$ (equivalently, $L$ vanishes on the subspace of eventually $0$ sequences and takes the constant $1$ sequence to $1$).
4. If $a \in (\mathbf{R}_{\ge 0})^\mathbf{N} \cap C$ then $La \ge 0$ (equivalently $L$ is monotonic).
5. If $a, b \in C$ then $ab := (a_n b_n) \in C$ and $L(ab) = (L a)(L b)$.
6. For $a \in C$ every subsequence $a'$ of $a$ is also in $C$ and $La = La'$.

But all of these are also satisfied by
$$C = \operatorname{span}\{a \text{ monotone bounded}\} = \{ a - b \mid a, b \text{ increasing and bounded} \}$$
(see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4377050/32766 for an alternate characterization) and $L = L_{\text{std}}|C$. So, **is there a similar list of "well-known" properties of $(C_{\text{std}}, L_{\text{std}})$ that implies $C \supseteq C_{\text{std}}$ and $L$ is an extension of $L_{\text{std}}$**? The implication should of course be "non-trivial", ie the list should not just include a definition of $\lim$. Given such a list, we could define $(L_{\text{std}}, C_{\text{std}})$ as the *minimal* pair satisfying that list.

Note that (1)-(4) are enough to show that $L$ restricted to $C \cap C_{\text{std}}$ agrees with $L_{\text{std}}$: if $a_\infty = \lim a_n$ then $a_n$ is eventually bounded between $a_\infty - \epsilon$ and $a_\infty + \epsilon$ and hence so is $La$. We don't even need all of (2), just that eventually constant sequences are in $C$.

(1), (3), (4) and (6) also imply that $C \subseteq C_{\text{std}}$. First note that if $a \in C$ then it has to be bounded, otherwise for each $N > 0$ either $a$ or $-a$ has a subsequence above $N$, so $|La| \ge N$ by monotonicity. Now if $a \in C$ is not convergent then it must have convergent subsequences with distinct limits, which forces a contradiction between (6) and that $L$ agrees with $L_{\text{std}}$ on $C \cap C_{\text{std}}$, as shown above. However I'd be generally interested if an answer provides a list that allows for $C \supsetneq C_{\text{std}}$.

*Remarks:*

- (1), (3) and (5) can be combined to: $C$ is a unital subalgebra of $\mathbf{R}^\mathbf{N}$ containing the ideal $C_0$ of eventually $0$ sequences and $L: C \to C/C_0 \to \mathbf{R}$ is a unital algebra homomorphism.
- It is plausible to me that (4) is implied by the other conditions. It could also be replaced by the (not obviously equivalent) condition $a \in C\cap (\mathbf{R}_{\ge 0})^{\mathbf{N}} \implies (\sqrt{a_n}) \in C$.

Comment: It's possible something like this is covered in the paper "[algebraic real analysis](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/20/10/20-10.pdf)"

Comment: I assume it’s cheating to replace (2) with “contains all sequences bounded between a monotone convergent sequence to $0$ and the $0$ sequence?”

Comment: Actually, since we have the monotone convergent sequences anyway, what about squeezing?  Ie if a and be in C then anything sandwiched between them is too? I feel like this gives you what you want, but maybe I’m missing something?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going for.

Comment: So @MW and I had the same idea, which is linked to Dedekind cuts. The usual way to define convergent sequences and limits would have been linked to Cauchy sequences. So it seems any construction method of $\mathbb R$ by completing $\mathbb Q$ can be used to define convergent sequences in $\mathbb R$. Tomorrow I'll give a try with a third method; for now I am going to sleep...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Upgarding my comment to an answer.]

[Edit: Elaborating a little more on the final axiom list.]

We can start with your axioms (1)-(4) and add a squeezing axiom (S) that says if $a=\{a_n\},b=\{b_n\}\in C$, and $L(a)=L(b)$, then for all $c=\{c_n\}$ such that $a_n\leq c_n\leq b_n$ for all $n$, we have $c\in C$ with $L(c)=L(a)=L(b)$.

Since $C$ is already guaranteed to contain bounded monotone sequences, this guarantees we get all convergent sequences, since an arbitrary convergent $\{a_n\}$ is sandwiched between  $\{\sup_{k\geq n}a_k\}$ and $\{\inf_{k\geq n}a_k\}$.

##### Minimality

You remarked in the original post that axioms (1)-(4) guarantee $L$ agrees with $L_{\text{std}}$ on the intersection $C\cap C_{\text{std}}$.  We conclude therefore that any $(C,L)$ satisfying the axioms (1)-(4) and (S) must extend $(C_{\text{std}}, L_{\text{std}})$, and so $(C_{\text{std}}, L_{\text{std}})$ is the minimal pair satisfying (1)-(4) and (S).

##### Nontrivial Extensions

[Cesàro Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-ces%c3%a0ro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn-to) also satisfies the axioms (1)-(4) and (S), so the axioms do allow for nontrivial extension.  Note that Cesàro convergence fails your axioms (5) (via $a= \{(-1)^n\}, b=\{(-1)^{n+1}\}$) and (6) (via $a=\{(-1)^n\}, a'=\{1\}$).

Another nontrivial extension arises with the set of sequences which converge on some subset (depending on the sequence) of asymptotic density $1$, with $L$ defined as the limit of the sequence restricted to any such subset on which it converges.  This satisfies (5) as well.  We could also replace asymptotic density $1$ subsets with any other nontrivial family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ closed under pairwise intersection.

##### Remark 1

Assuming we have linearity (i.e., axiom (1)), the squeezing axiom (S) is equivalent to the axiom that if $a=\{a_n\}\in C$ is a non-negative sequence with $L(a)=0$, and $0\leq b_n \leq a_n$ for all $n$, then $b=\{b_n\}\in C$ with $L(b)=0$.

##### Remark 2

As you suggested in the comments, axiom (1) can be relaxed to say that $L$ is $\mathbb Z$-linear.  If this is done, we still have $(C_{\text{std}},L_{\text{std}})$ as the minimal pair satisfying the axioms (1)-(4) and (S).  In this case, I do not know if $\mathbb R$-linearity is implied by the axioms.

We could further relax axiom (1) to say that $C$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, and $L$ is $\mathbb Z$-linear.  With this further weakening, we yet again have $(C_{\text{std}},L_{\text{std}})$ minimal among pairs satisfying the axioms, but now, axioms (1)-(4) and (S) are insufficient to recover the vector space assumption.

In fact, let $c=\{(-1)^n\}$, let $C=C_{\text{std}} + \mathbb Z c$, define $L(a+\lambda c)=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ for $a\in C_{\text{std}}$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb Z$, and observe that $(C,L)$ satisfies the axioms, yet is not a vector subspace.

(1)-(4) are easily satisfied, and to prove (S), we argue as follows, using the equivalent formulation of (S) from the first remark:
Suppose $0\leq b \leq a+\lambda c $, for some $\lambda\in \mathbb Z$ and $a\in C_{\text{std}}$, with $L(a+\lambda c)=0$, i.e., for all $n$ we have $$0\leq b_n \leq a_n +\lambda(-1)^n\text{,}$$
and $a_n\to 0$.

Then looking only at the even terms and passing to the limit, we see that $0\leq \lambda$, and likewise the odd terms show us that $0\leq -\lambda$, whereby $\lambda=0$ and $b\in C_{\text{std}}$, and $L(b)=0$.

Comment: It seems we had the same idea, and posted it within the same minute, despite the question being posted 16 hours before. This is quite fun. :-)

Comment: @ronno Good catch, fixed it.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni great minds :)

Comment: Your squeezing axiom states " $a=\{a_n\},b=\{b_n\}\in C$, and $L(a)=L(b)$ ". The fact that $L(a)=L(b)$ means we cannot use that for the two constant sequences that sandwich an arbitrary convergent sequence, as you propose.

Comment: I'm not sandwiching them with constant sequences.  I'm sandwiching them with monotone sequences.

Comment: You can also weaken $\mathbf{R}$-linearity to $\mathbf{Z}$-linearity: if $a, b \in C$ then $a \pm b \in C$ and $L(a \pm b) = L(a) \pm L(b)$.

Comment: @ronno I thought I could do that and in fact briefly posted a lengthy explanation, but it was flawed.  The difficulty I had was establishing scalar multiplication.  Though I was trying to prove R-Linearity from Z-linearity.  If you don't care about recovering R-linearity then I guess you can indeed do as you suggest.

Comment: @MW Oh yes that's true, sorry. And then, in order for $L$ to be correctly defined, we need both linearity (in (1) of OP), and positivity ((4) of OP). That's a place where our two proposals are fundamentally different.

Comment: @MW right, $\mathbf{Z}$-linearity is enough to make $L$ agree with $L_{std}$ on $C_{std}$ but I don't see how to get that $L$ is $\mathbf{R}$-linear on all of $C$ without more assumptions either.

Answer (score 3):

**Proposal 1**, which reuses some of your ideas:

- (1) $C$ contains all constant sequences. If $a$ is the constant sequence with value $a_\infty$, $La = a_\infty$.
- (2) If $a \in C$, every subsequence $a'$ of $a$ is also in $C$, and $La'=La$.
- (3) A partial order on sequences is defined by $a \le b$ iff $\forall n, a_n \le b_n$. Then $\forall a, b \in C, a \le b \Rightarrow La \le Lb$.
- (4) Let $M_<(a) = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid \exists b \in C, b \le a, Lb=x\}$ and $M_>(a) = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid \exists b \in C, b \ge a, Lb=x\}$.
  We can prove (below) that all elements of $M_<(a)$ are $\le$ to all elements of $M_>(a)$.
  Then if $M_<(a)$ and $M_>(a)$ are both non-empty, and $M_<(a) \cup M_>(a) = \mathbb R$, then $a \in C$ and $La$ is defined to be the element that separates $M_<(a)$ from $M_>(a)$ (same as Dedekind cuts, this is were $\mathbb R$ being complete is used).

$C$ is defined to be the smallest set (for inclusion) that verifies these 4 properties.

Proof that all elements of $M_<(a)$ are $\le$ to all elements of $M_>(a)$:
$\forall x \in M_<(a), \exists b \in C, b \le a, Lb=x$
$\forall x' \in M_>(a), \exists b' \in C, b' \ge a, Lb'=x'$
By transitivity, $b \le b'$, so $Lb = x \le Lb' = x'$

These 4 properties define convergent subsequences and their limits, because:

- Eventually constant sequences are in $C$ due to (1) and (2).
- For any convergent sequence $a$ we can be bound it below by an eventually constant sequence whose limit is as close to the limit of $a$ as we want; and similarly, we can bound above as close as we want; so $M_<(a) \cup M_>(a) = \mathbb R$.
- For any unbounded sequence $a$, at least one of $M_<(a)$ or $M_>(a)$ will be empty, so $a \notin C$.
- For any bounded, non-convergent sequence $a$, there exists at least 2 different accumulation points $x \lt x'$ (there is at least one because the sequence is bounded, and if there is only one, the sequence is convergent). So open interval $(x, x')$ is not in $M_<(a) \cup M_>(a)$, so $a \notin C$.

**Proposal 2**
Define $T(a)$ as the set of open intervals that contain $a$.
Define $T^∗(a)$ as the union of $T(b)$ for all subsequences $b$ of $a$.
Then by definition $a$ is convergent iff $T^∗(a)$ is stable by finite intersection.
Note that we get also sequences that "converge" to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$; to remove them, use only bounded sequences.

That defines $C$. Then for $a \in C$, define $L(a)$ as the (infinite) intersection of all elements of $T^*(a)$.

Comment: I might be missing something but it seems from your post that the four properties by themselves guarantee $(C,L)= (C_{\text{std}},L_{\text{std}})$, so you don't have to bother defining $C$ as the smallest such set.

Comment: @MW Adding "the smallest" is necessary because set $C$'s definition is self-referencing in property (4), i.e. it is impredicative. You can add whatever non-convergent sequences (plus all its subsequences) you want to $C$, the four properties are still valid ($La$ cannot be correctly defined, due to (2), but we are talking about $C$ not $L$). Some axiomatic definitions of $\mathbb N$ exhibit the same problem. Another way of solving it would be to add in (4): " if $M_<(a)$ or $M_>(a)$ is empty, or $M_<(a) \cup M_>(a) \ne \mathbb R$, then $a \notin C$ "; but I feel it less convincing.

Comment: @MW Actually, no, we cannot solve the problem by adding in (4): " if $M_<(a)$ or $M_>(a)$ is empty, or $M_<(a) \cup M_>(a) \ne \mathbb R$, then $a \notin C$ ": that would still be self-referencing, so existence + unicity of $C$ would not be ensured.

Comment: Hmm, I might be getting stuck on the precise meaning of "$C$ is defined to be the smallest set (for inclusion) that verifies these 4 properties."  I was taking "verifies" to be synonymous with "satisfies", but I'm starting to suspect that may not be right?  It might be that I'm too bereft of knowledge to fully digest your approach, if you perhaps are using concepts from mathematical logic for example.

Comment: @MW Indeed by "verifies" I mean "satisfies". Actually this requires proving that there is a set $C_0$ that is included in all other sets $C$ that satisfy the four properties. This is done by proving that for any $C$ satisfying all four properties, all convergent sequences belong to $C$; so $C_{std} \subset C_0$. Then we have to prove that $C_{std}$ satisfies the four properties. This is what I do in the end of the text, but I admit it is very sketchy.