# How can i write $f(x)=\cos(x)$ as the difference of two monotonically increasing functions?

Tags: analysis

This is a Question from an Analysis 1 exam. The question is as follows: Decide if the functions $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be written as the difference of two monotonically increasing functions

a) $f(x) = \cos(x)$

b) $f(x) = x^2$

For the moment I’m working on a) my first thought would be to use the MVT and receive something in the form of $\cos(x)+2x = -\sin(x)-2x$ but as we see -$\sin(x)$ is not monotonically increasing. Obviously one could also answer with $\cos(x) = (\cos(x)+2x) - 2x$ but I fear this answer would not be accepted by my professor.
If you have any tips or answers for either a) or b) id be grateful

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why do you fear that answer won't be accepted by your professor?

Comment: You already have a solution $\cos(x) = (\cos(x)+2x) - 2x$, why do you think it would not be accepted?

Comment: I’m not sure if i should use cos(x) to describe cos(x) and my professor has given some hints and the hint was to use the MVT.

Comment: The MVT helps to show that $\cos(x)+2x$ is increasing ...

Comment: What does $IR$ mean?

Comment: It should be underlined that this property (being the difference of two increasing functions) is characteristic of the BV ([Bounded Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation)) family. It is in particular a mean to answer to the question.

Comment: For a good explanation about BV functions, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141346/305862)

Answer (score 2):

This should work
$$
\cos(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2(2k)}}{(2(2k))!} - 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2(2k+1)}}{(2(2k+1))!}
$$

Comment: Those functions are increasing for $x \ge 0$, but not for $x < 0$.

Comment: Great Example ! [ +1 ] Suggestion 1 : I think , you should include some content to Prove that the two terms are indeed monotonic. Suggestion 2 : You might include some Image Plot of the two terms.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's an Analysis 1 exam, you can use differentiation to help construct such functions. We note the desired subtractor as $g(x)$ (then $f=(f+g)-g$ should be our answer), and to be convenient, just suppose $g(x)$ is continuouslly differentiable.

For a), we need $\begin{cases}
-\sin(x)+g'(x)>0 \\
g'(x)>0
\end{cases}\Rightarrow g'(x)>\max\left\{\sin(x), 0\right\}$, and letting $g(x)=2x$ (just as the construction in your answer) helps;

For b), we need $\begin{cases}
2x+g'(x)>0 \\
g'(x)>0
\end{cases}$. We put $g'(x)=x^2+2\Rightarrow g(x)=\dfrac{1}{3}x^3+2x$ gives the solution.